# How do you update cells based on data validation

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm creating a budget with Google Sheets and I want to update totals based on the category. I'm using Data Validation to categorize the transactions but how would I create a button that updates all categories based on the transactions using App Scripts. Basically, I'm trying to use SUM to add everything up but only if they are categorized in a specific category. Thanks for any help that's offered.

Comment: Pls, can you share an example (simplified spreadsheet) of what you expect?

Comment: Please checkout https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets, https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus and https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs. If you need further help, please add a brief description of your search efforts and make you question more specific.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example:

```
function createCategories() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet0');
  const sh1 = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  const r = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInRange(sh1.getRange('A2:A22'));
  sh.getRange(2,4,20,1).setDataValidation(r);
}

function catTotals() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet0');
  const vs = sh.getRange(2,1,sh.getLastRow() - 1,4).getValues();
  let sums ={pA:[]};
  vs.forEach((r,i) => {
    if(!sums.hasOwnProperty(r[3])) {
      sums[r[3]]=r[2];
      sums.pA.push(r[3]);
    } else {
      sums[r[3]] += r[2];
    }
  });
  let html = "<style>td,th{border:1px solid black;}</style><table><tr><th>Category</th><th>Total</th></tr>";
  sums.pA.forEach(p => {
    html += `<tr><td>${p}</td><td>${sums[p]}</td></tr>`
  });
  html += '</table><br /><input type="button" value="Exit" onClick="google.script.host.close()" />';
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html),'Category Totals')
  
}
```

[image]